# What is it called when staff at a clothes shop serves a customer

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

Is this service called サービス or are there better verbs? e.g. 接する

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By far the most commonly-used word would be 「[接客]{せっきゃく}」 for the noun and 「接客する」 for the verb.  It is used specifically in business where one serves a customer.

「[接]{せっ}する」 has a much broader range of meanings and therefore, it is often used in ***non-business*** situations as well to mean "to meet", "to treat", "to come into cantact with", etc.

The word 「サービス」 is tricky in that it is ***not*** always used the same way the word "service" is in English.  It can be used to mean 「接客」 but it is also quite often used to refer to "a ***freebie***" or "a special discount" of some sort that a business provides.